# when I switch my Rails open source engine to Postgres for testing, I get `can't modify frozen Array`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For my open source gem [Hot Glue](https://github.com/hot-glue-for-rails/hot-glue), I'm trying to switch the testing paradigm from using SQLite to Postgres.

All of this code is visible on my gem at github, and I will provide links to the SHAs here.

When I modify the `config/database.yml` file to add a Postgres service, I'm running into an error:

`can't modify frozen Array`

this is happening in the spec_helper while it is attempting to initialize the dummy at by calling

`Dummy::Application.initialize!`

the failure can be seen here:
https://github.com/hot-glue-for-rails/hot-glue/actions/runs/5063433354/jobs/9090044359

and the commit that has caused this failure is here:
https://github.com/hot-glue-for-rails/hot-glue/pull/77/commits/ef3cf4526fba6eae8b0a8315317662c4bafe7ae1

All it does is change the database. on the branch https://github.com/hot-glue-for-rails/hot-glue/pull/77, the commit shown causes the failure, but does not actually implement Postgres on the Github actions test file.

I have also attempted, quite laboriously, to get Postgres actually working on Github actions, which can be seen here in my sad 39-commit trial & error run (somehow github actions makes this process extremely tedious)

https://github.com/hot-glue-for-rails/hot-glue/pull/76

So, I know the root cause is changing the database adapter, but even when I implement the new database in github action as a service, it still gives this error:

Since it is open source anyway you can actually pull my branches and try it yourself. they can be seen at:

https://github.com/hot-glue-for-rails/hot-glue/pulls

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/lib/hot_glue_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: Dummy::Application.initialize!

FrozenError:
  can't modify frozen Array: ["/home/runner/work/hot-glue/hot-glue/dummy/app/channels", "/home/runner/work/hot-glue/hot-glue/dummy/app/controllers", "/home/runner/work/hot-glue/hot-glue/dummy/app/helpers", "/home/runner/work/hot-glue/hot-glue/dummy/app/jobs", "/home/runner/work/hot-glue/hot-glue/dummy/app/mailers", "/home/runner/work/hot-glue/hot-glue/dummy/app/models", "/home/runner/work/hot-glue/hot-glue/dummy/app/models/concerns", "/home/runner/work/hot-glue/hot-glue/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/devise-4.9.2/app/controllers", "/home/runner/work/hot-glue/hot-glue/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/devise-4.9.2/app/helpers", "/home/runner/work/hot-glue/hot-glue/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/devise-4.9.2/app/mailers", "/home/runner/work/hot-glue/hot-glue/app/helpers", "/home/runner/work/hot-glue/hot-glue/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/actionmailbox-7.0.4.3/app/controllers", "/home/runner/work/hot-glue/hot-glue/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/actionmailbox-7.0.4.3/app/jobs", "/home/runner/work/hot-glue/hot-glue/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/actionmailbox-7.0.4.3/app/models", "/home/runner/work/hot-glue/hot-glue/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activestorage-7.0.4.3/app/controllers", "/home/runner/work/hot-glue/hot-glue/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activestorage-7.0.4.3/app/controllers/concerns", "/home/runner/work/hot-glue/hot-glue/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activestorage-7.0.4.3/app/jobs", "/home/runner/work/hot-glue/hot-glue/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activestorage-7.0.4.3/app/models"]
# ./spec/spec_helper.rb:34:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/lib/hot_glue_spec.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.
```

Comment: I think what I'm looking at here is that on Github actions, the DUmmy app must be trying to be initialized twice, whereas locally, somehow this does not initialize twice or the Array is not frozen. Either way, it passes with this hack: https://github.com/hot-glue-for-rails/hot-glue/pull/77/commits/a664f62d8d12214cc6cd4a6666a36ddcc7fc9e57